# Salto de línea en Python 3.6.4

Tags: python

¿Cómo se podría escribir la siguiente cadena?

```
"Hola, me llamo Fulano,

y esto es un salto de línea

y este otro"
```

He intentado hacerlo con `/n` y no me sale:

```
>>> "Hola, me llamo Fulano, \n y esto es un salto de línea, \n y este otro"
'Hola, me llamo Fulano, \n y esto es un salto de línea, \n y este otro'
```

Comment: Lo que se muestra es la salida del método `__repr__` (representación del objeto que generalmente puede usarse para reconstruirlo vía  `eval `), si imprimes la cadena te mostrará los saltos de línea correctamente ( `método __str__ `). `>>> print("Hola, me llamo Fulano, \n y esto es un salto de línea, \n y este otro")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que entiendo de tu pregunta es que quieres dejar un espacio, como dividiendo un párrafo, si es así pues yo hago esto en esos casos

```
print("texto 1")
print("")
print("texto 2")
```

espero que sea eso
(se que la pregunta es vieja pero respondo por si alguien le sirve)

Answer (score 9):

El **salto de línea** es exactamente como lo tienes en tu pregunta y para verificarlo sólo debes utilizar la instrucción **print()** como te muestro en el siguiente **código**:

```
>>> print("Hola, me llamo Fulano, \n y esto es un salto de línea, \n y este otro")
Hola, me llamo Fulano,
 y esto es un salto de línea,
 y este otro
```

Si quieres probar tu mismo el ejemplo puedes hacerlo en este editor: [Editor Online Python](https://paiza.io/projects/qIOFKdc5jm4SpVIs2I-5Eg?language=python3)

Espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: Y si lo que quiero imprimir es demasiado extenso, como salto linea en el editor, manteniendo el mismo comando sin repetir?)

Comment: No comprendo bien tu pregunta. Saltar en el editor? No quieres que se vea como tal al correr el programa? Disculpa la tardanza en contestar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la triple comilla, es muy funcional no sólamente permite agregar texto, sino que te habilita para incluir las variables también:

```
print('''
  Hola, me llamo Fulano,
  y esto es un salto de línea
  y este otro"
''')
```